# Laravel check if related children not empty

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have a collection I'm returning along the lines of this

```
form : {
    groups : [
         {
             title : 'group 1'
             fields : [
                 {
                     name: 'field 1',
                     contents:[
                         {
                             value: 'Filled in'
                         }
                     ]
                 }
                 {
                     name: 'field 2',
                     contents :[
                         {
                             value: 'Filled in'
                         }
                     ]
                 }
             ]
         },
         {
             title : 'group 2'
             fields : [
                 {
                     name: 'field 1',
                     contents:[]
                 }
                 {
                     name: 'field 2',
                     contents :[]
                 }
             ]
         }
     ]
 }
```

Which I then loop through like this

```
@foreach($form->groups as $group)
  {{ $group->title }}
  @foreach(group->fields as $field)
    {{ $field->name }} {{ $field->contents[0]->value }}
    ...
```

But I'm in a situation where I may have empty `field.contents` but I'm still echoing out the group title, for instance the above would echo

---

#### group 1

Field 1: Filled in
Field 2: Filled in

#### group 2

---

How can I check that each $group's->fields[]->contents are !empty before writing the title?

<sup>Apologies for any typos, it is very, very late</sup>

**Edit**

I think I need to do something along the lines of:

```
if( ! $group->fields->sum('contents[0].value') )
```

Is there a way I can pass an argument to the `sum` function?

Comment: What is `contents`, can you provide some example?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
@foreach($form->groups as $group)
  {{ $group->title }}
  @foreach(group->fields as $field)
    @if(!empty($field->contents))
    {{ $field->name }} {{ $field->contents[0]->value }}
    @endif
    ...
```

Comment: Hmmm it doesn't work, as `$field` isn't an object, but an array (`$fields`)... of objects, with arrays of objects : / I almost need to do `if( ! $fields->sum('contents[0].value') )`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing all the specifics I would probably eliminate the elements you don't want before passing it to the view. By using toArray() on the collection and running :

```
foreach( $form as $key => $groups ){

    if( ! isset( $groups['fields']['contents'][0] ) ){

        unset( $form[$key] );

    }

}
```

Then of course you would have to update you view code

```
@foreach($form['groups'] as $group)...
```